# How to create a dynamic date generator in groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a simple date generator code where it selects a date from now to 120 days.

However, I want my dates to be a little more clever. I only want it to select from months *May, June, July and August* only.

So if the current date is ***before May***, then select a date at random within one of those four months for this year.
Else if the current date is ***past June***, the select a date from any of the 4 months for next year.

How can this be written in groovy?

Below is the current date generator.

```
//Defines Start and End Dates for holiday departure date search
Random random = new Random();
date = new Date()
def startDate = date + random.nextInt(100 + 120)
sDate = startDate.format("yyyy-MM-dd")

testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue('arrivaldate', sDate);
```

Comment: what if current date falls in May 1st to 30th June?

Comment: indeed, I echo the past comment. My algorithm currently returns dates from the current year, but after the current date for dates between May 1st and June 30th. On June 30th it rolls to using dates from next year, but the problem, as the previous comment suggests, is currently not defined for these dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Groovy Script which does what you intended to do.

Note that below script would throw an error if current date falls in the date range which is missing in the question.

> Not implemented for the days between 1st May to 30th June

Please follow the comments inline.

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd'

def getNumberInRange = { min, max -> new Random().nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min }

def isTodayBeforeMay = { Calendar.MONTH < 5 }

def isTodayAfterJune = { Calendar.MONTH > 6 }

//Get the number of days between today and given date
def getDifferenceDays = { targetDate, closure ->
    def strDate = closure (targetDate)
    def futureDate = new Date().parse(dateFormat, strDate)
    TimeCategory.minus(futureDate, new Date()).days
}

//Get the offset between today and max date i.e.,31 august
def getOffSetDays = { date ->
    //Need to change the date range if needed.
    //As per OP, May to August is mentioned below
    def max = getDifferenceDays(date) { "${it[Calendar.YEAR]}-08-31" }
    def min = getDifferenceDays(date) { "${it[Calendar.YEAR]}-05-01" }
    getNumberInRange(min, max)
}


def now = new Date()
def nextYearNow = now.updated(year: now[Calendar.YEAR] + 1)

def selected
def finalDate

println "Today : $now"
println "Next year same date : $nextYearNow"

if (isTodayBeforeMay()) {
    selected = now    
} else if (isTodayAfterJune()) {
    selected = nextYearNow
} else {
    //It is not mentioned what should happened for the mentioned period by OP
    throw new Error("Not implemented for the days between 1st May to 30th June")
}

def offset = getOffSetDays(selected)

//Add the offset days to now
use(TimeCategory) {
    finalDate = now + offset.days
}
println "Final future date is : $finalDate"
println "Final future date is(formatted) : ${finalDate.format(dateFormat)}"

//set the date at test case level property
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('NEXT_DATE', finalDate.format(dateFormat))
```

In order to get the date evaluated

- Use `${#TestCase#NEXT_DATE}` in requests
- Use `context.expand('${#TestCase#NEXT_DATE}')` in groovy script (string is returned)

**NOTE:** `println` can be replaced with `log.info` in the above script if you want to see the output in soapui tool. Otherwise, print statements are shown int log files.

You can quickly try the above script online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5094196687929344)</kbd>

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(*edited after clarification by op*)

```
def getRandomDate(Date now, Random random) {
  def year         = now.year + (now.month > 5 ? 1 : 0)
  def allDates     = (new Date(year, 4, 1)..new Date(year, 7, 31))
  def allowedDates = allDates.findAll { now < it }

  allowedDates[random.nextInt(allowedDates.size())]
}

// example usage
def now    = new Date()
def random = new Random()

100.times { 
  def today      = now + it*3
  def randomDate = getRandomDate(now+it*3, random)
  println "today: ${today.format('yyyy MMM dd')} ==> random date: ${randomDate.format('yyyy MMM dd')}"
}
```

an execution of the above prints out something along the lines of:

```
today: 2017 Feb 25 ==> random date: 2017 Jul 21
today: 2017 Feb 28 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 03
today: 2017 Mar 03 ==> random date: 2017 Jun 21
today: 2017 Mar 06 ==> random date: 2017 May 21
today: 2017 Mar 09 ==> random date: 2017 Jun 05
today: 2017 Mar 12 ==> random date: 2017 May 03
today: 2017 Mar 15 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 04
today: 2017 Mar 18 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 17
today: 2017 Mar 21 ==> random date: 2017 Jul 09
today: 2017 Mar 24 ==> random date: 2017 Jul 11
today: 2017 Mar 27 ==> random date: 2017 Jul 16
today: 2017 Mar 30 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 09
today: 2017 Apr 02 ==> random date: 2017 Jul 09
today: 2017 Apr 05 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 05
today: 2017 Apr 08 ==> random date: 2017 Jul 19
today: 2017 Apr 11 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 10
today: 2017 Apr 14 ==> random date: 2017 Jun 21
today: 2017 Apr 17 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 03
today: 2017 Apr 20 ==> random date: 2017 May 02
today: 2017 Apr 23 ==> random date: 2017 Jul 04
today: 2017 Apr 26 ==> random date: 2017 Jun 13
today: 2017 Apr 29 ==> random date: 2017 May 02
today: 2017 May 02 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 01
today: 2017 May 05 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 07
today: 2017 May 08 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 20
today: 2017 May 11 ==> random date: 2017 Jun 29
today: 2017 May 14 ==> random date: 2017 May 18
today: 2017 May 17 ==> random date: 2017 Jun 11
today: 2017 May 20 ==> random date: 2017 May 26
today: 2017 May 23 ==> random date: 2017 Jul 06
today: 2017 May 26 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 29
today: 2017 May 29 ==> random date: 2017 Jun 02
today: 2017 Jun 01 ==> random date: 2017 Jun 09
today: 2017 Jun 04 ==> random date: 2017 Jun 07
today: 2017 Jun 07 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 09
today: 2017 Jun 10 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 02
today: 2017 Jun 13 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 04
today: 2017 Jun 16 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 09
today: 2017 Jun 19 ==> random date: 2017 Jun 22
today: 2017 Jun 22 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 16
today: 2017 Jun 25 ==> random date: 2017 Aug 13
today: 2017 Jun 28 ==> random date: 2017 Jul 05
today: 2017 Jul 01 ==> random date: 2018 Jun 18
today: 2017 Jul 04 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 29
today: 2017 Jul 07 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 13
today: 2017 Jul 10 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 26
today: 2017 Jul 13 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 23
today: 2017 Jul 16 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 12
today: 2017 Jul 19 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 24
today: 2017 Jul 22 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 20
today: 2017 Jul 25 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 28
today: 2017 Jul 28 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 29
today: 2017 Jul 31 ==> random date: 2018 May 02
today: 2017 Aug 03 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 19
today: 2017 Aug 06 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 05
today: 2017 Aug 09 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 28
today: 2017 Aug 12 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 16
today: 2017 Aug 15 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 04
today: 2017 Aug 18 ==> random date: 2018 May 30
today: 2017 Aug 21 ==> random date: 2018 May 02
today: 2017 Aug 24 ==> random date: 2018 May 01
today: 2017 Aug 27 ==> random date: 2018 May 10
today: 2017 Aug 30 ==> random date: 2018 May 04
today: 2017 Sep 02 ==> random date: 2018 Jun 30
today: 2017 Sep 05 ==> random date: 2018 May 05
today: 2017 Sep 08 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 27
today: 2017 Sep 11 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 14
today: 2017 Sep 14 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 15
today: 2017 Sep 17 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 12
today: 2017 Sep 20 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 24
today: 2017 Sep 23 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 28
today: 2017 Sep 26 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 26
today: 2017 Sep 29 ==> random date: 2018 Jun 27
today: 2017 Oct 02 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 15
today: 2017 Oct 05 ==> random date: 2018 Jun 27
today: 2017 Oct 08 ==> random date: 2018 Jun 01
today: 2017 Oct 11 ==> random date: 2018 Jun 12
today: 2017 Oct 14 ==> random date: 2018 Jun 06
today: 2017 Oct 17 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 02
today: 2017 Oct 20 ==> random date: 2018 May 05
today: 2017 Oct 23 ==> random date: 2018 Jun 15
today: 2017 Oct 26 ==> random date: 2018 Jun 05
today: 2017 Oct 29 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 12
today: 2017 Nov 01 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 29
today: 2017 Nov 04 ==> random date: 2018 May 15
today: 2017 Nov 07 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 03
today: 2017 Nov 10 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 16
today: 2017 Nov 13 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 21
today: 2017 Nov 16 ==> random date: 2018 May 06
today: 2017 Nov 19 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 15
today: 2017 Nov 22 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 03
today: 2017 Nov 25 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 15
today: 2017 Nov 28 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 29
today: 2017 Dec 01 ==> random date: 2018 May 06
today: 2017 Dec 04 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 31
today: 2017 Dec 07 ==> random date: 2018 May 12
today: 2017 Dec 10 ==> random date: 2018 May 01
today: 2017 Dec 13 ==> random date: 2018 Aug 31
today: 2017 Dec 16 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 17
today: 2017 Dec 19 ==> random date: 2018 Jul 24
```

Essentially we pick a random date out of a list of allowed dates.

Performance could be improved by not creating the `allowedDates` list on every call.

Some of the date methods are deprecated. If deprecations are important, you might want to use Calendar instead.

The groovy range `..` operator on dates return a date range containing all the dates between the two given dates, inclusive.

I have left `now` external to the method to make testing easier and I have left `random` external to the method as I believe re-creating new instances of random on every call is detrimental to the quality of the random distribution generated.

**Note 1:** For dates between May 1st and June 30th, the problem definition is unclear. For these dates the code returns a random date from the current year,  excluding past dates. I.e. on June 15th, the algorithm would return a random date from this year between June 16th and August 31st. On July 1st it would return a random date from next year, between May 1st and August 31st.

**Note 2:** Alternate version without deprecated date calls and using calendar:

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*
import java.util.GregorianCalendar as Cal

def getRandomDate(Date now, Random random) {
  def cal = new Cal(time: now)

  // use current year if current date is before july, otherwise next year
  def year         = cal.get(YEAR) + (cal.get(MONTH) > 5 ? 1 : 0)
  def allDates     = (new Cal(year, 4, 1).time..new Cal(year, 7, 31).time)
  def allowedDates = allDates.findAll { now < it }

  allowedDates[random.nextInt(allowedDates.size())]
}
```